# Twitter volume API

Tags: api, twitter

Is there an API for retrieving the number of tweets containing a certain keyword in Twitter conversations?

I read the Twitter API docs but it seems there is nothing to do that in the official API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. You can do the counting yourself -- sort of. Use the streaming API to filter for the keyword and count the results. This will work perfectly unless your keyword happens to be popular enough to drive the count above the 1% threshold for streaming results. At that point, mixed in with your results will be LIMIT messages containing the number of tweets missed since the stream was open. This number is cumulative, so you would add it to your running count once at the end of the period for which you are counting. However, it is not quite that simple (hence the "sort of" above). These LIMIT messages fluctuate for some reason which Twitter refuses to divulge. Hopefully, they are in the ball park and get you close to the count you are looking for.

Comment: Great! Thank you very much